# What is the use case for keepfilter and removefilters?

Tags: dax

Example:

```
Calculate(expr, FILTER(ALL(Sales), Sales['Amt']>1000))
```

This is bad practice because it works on entire Sales table. To improve it I remove filter and write:

```
Calculate(expr, Sales['Amt']>1000)
```

The above is syntactic sugar for:

```
Calculate(expr, FILTER(ALL(Sales['Amt']), Sales['Amt']>1000))
```

So it removes the filter context and evaluates the filter.

Whereas to keep the filter context I could have written:

```
Calculate(expr, FILTER(VALUES(Sales['Amt']), Sales['Amt']>1000))
```

With this knowledge, I'm trying to understand what is the use case for KEEPFILTERS and REMOVEFILTERS. Any example will be useful.

Comment: `CALCULATE(expr, Sales['Amt']>1000)` is **not** equivalent to `CALCULATE(expr, FILTER(ALL(Sales), Sales['Amt']>1000))`; it is equivalent to `CALCULATE(expr, FILTER(ALL(Sales['Amt']), Sales['Amt']>1000))`.

Comment: Good article on `KEEPFILTERS` [here](https://dax.tips/2020/03/23/dax-keepfilters/).